# System shutdown without password in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I'm writing a QT application which has a shutdown button. I want to shutdown system with this button but when I use the shell command "shutdown -h now" the system asks for password.
I want to shutdown without password.

My QT code is:

```
QObject *parent;
myProcess = new QProcess(this);
QString command= "sudo shutdown";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-h " << "now"  ;
myProcess->start(command,arguments);
```

Comment: Have you thought about permissions?  Either you make your program setuid (bad idea), make `/sbin/shutdown` setuid (bad idea) or add the current user to the `/etc/sudoers` file so you can run `sudo /sbin/shutdown` from your program (hassle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the user running the process is in the sudoers file.
Use `visudo` to alter the sudoers file and add something like the following:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

*hth*

Comment: For those having trouble with this command...you probably need to make it the LAST line of the sudoers file.  If there are any other commands after it, they will probably interfere.

Comment: You will also have to add following in /etc/sudoers

Defaults    exempt_group=<usergroup>

Answer (score 2):

Look at going through `gksudo`/`kdesudo` for calling `reboot`, one of those should be on most Linux installations. 
They're simple wrappers that will ask the user for their password to confirm elevating privileges to `root` and, in your case, calling `reboot` or `shutdown`.

Just play nice with the rest of the system and let `shutdown` ask the user for his password.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling a shell command you can call reboot directly to halt or reboot the system. See "man 2 reboot". But you will still get a permission error if the user does not have the CAP_SYS_BOOT capability. With sudo or suid binary, as described in the comment above, you will get this capability (and more).

You can also set the CAP_SYS_BOOT capability for your binary with the setcap program or similar. Remember that this will have to be done after each time the program is recompiled, and you have to use sudo to use setcap.